# jQuery function similar to closest that will return elements outside of the parent chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any jQuery function similar to closest() that will return elements outside of the parent chain, traversing sideways? For example, I want to call a function foo() on the div source that would return the div target. I know I could navigate using parent() and siblings(), but I need something generic that would go as many levels as needed, up, sideways and down?

```
var allsources = $('.source');

allsources.click(function()){
  $(this).closest('.target').hide();
});

<div class="row">
  <div>
     <div class="target" ></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="source"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div>
     <div class="target" ></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="source"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

My definition of closest: you have an element source. Try to find it down. If find more than one, return one that is less node hoops down/next/prev. If not found, go one level up, and try to find again. Repeat until no parent.

Comment: Up, sideways *and* down? Thats, uhm... the whole dom tree

Comment: Exactly, you have an ID, id is unique (right?) so you just use the id selector

Comment: Would nextAll() or prevAll() be useful here?

Comment: that would return all targets on the page. My idea is to use with classes as well, and I would like just the closest, not all of them

Comment: @tie, what you mean by *closest* is not clear. There are two axes and four directions to take into account (ancestor and sibling chains). For instance, what if there are two target elements, one two ranks higher in the ancestor chain and the other two ranks across in the sibling chain? Which one is closest?

Comment: Looking at your edit, why on earth are you avoiding the obvious `.parents('.row').find('.target')`?

Comment: If there was such function I wanted to use that in different contexts/pages where the html markup is not always the same, I could not have the div.row

Comment: An upvote for the question for being hard, fun, and interesting :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, by closest, you mean "travel up as little as possible, then anywhere downwards", then you can do

```
$("#source")
  .closest(":has(.target)")
  .find(".target:first")  //make sure we only select one element in case of a tie
```

In your case, it would be better to specify the common parent directly:

```
$(this)
  .closest(".row")
  .find(".target")        //there's no tie here, no need to arbitrate
```

Comment: Good idea, but this potentially returns several elements, not *the* "closest" one.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi then it needs to be specified _which_ "closest" element to choose. I'll make an arbitrary choice. Edited

Comment: useful but this would also get the elements in the current parent

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one. As has been commented, how do you define closest in this context? Assuming you can decide on some rules; for example:

Traverse up: 3pt
Traverse down: 2pts
Move sideways: 1pts

And then consider the item with the lowest points to be "closest" then it would be easy enough to author a plugin, named something such as `closestAll`, which would do the recursive traversal of the whole dom tree to determine the closest item.

However, looking at your recent edit, one (of many!) *right* solutions to the problem stated is:

```
var allsources = $('.source');

allsources.click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.row').find('.target').hide();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zCvJM/ (Source A only hides Target A, Same for B)

Comment: it works with the .row on markup, but I just would like something generic that would not rely on the .row

Comment: @tie - if you dont know the structure of your HTML, then there is a problem with your design. There is no "1 size fits all selector", its almost impossible to define (see my simplistic attempt above).

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly the structure of the dom and level of nesting, have you consider to use the eq() method

```
$(this).parents().eq(1).prev().children(".target")
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't think there is a way to do this other than basically querying the whole DOM:</strike>

```
$('#target')
```

Because if you want to go up and across (never mind down as well) then the target element isn't related to the child element.  If you also want to check for the presence of the child element you will have to do that separately.

***-Edit:***

After reading your comment on wanting to find the closest element regardless of whether it is a parent, I think you will have to write a custom function to crawl back up the dom one node at a time.  I have tested the following and it works:

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">   
        <div id="source"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div class="target" rel="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3">
        <div>
            <div class="target" rel="wrong"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tgt = findClosest($('#source'), '.target');
    if (tgt != undefined) {
        alert(tgt.attr('rel'));
    }
});


function findClosest(source, targetSel) {
    var crawledNodes = $();
    var target = null;

    // Go up
    source.parents().each(function () {
        console.log(crawledNodes.index($(this)));
        if (crawledNodes.index($(this)) == -1 && target == null) {
            crawledNodes.add($(this));
            target = findTarget($(this), targetSel);

            // Go across
            $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                console.log("Sibling");
                if (crawledNodes.index($(this)) == -1 && target == null) {
                    crawledNodes.add($(this));
                    target = findTarget($(this), targetSel);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return target;
}

function findTarget(el, targetSel) {
    console.log(targetSel);
    var target = el.find(targetSel);
    if (target.size() > 0) {
        return target.eq(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad start, but too easy to break. For example, if you move `#child3` to before `#child1`, then your method finds the wrong element ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SFen/)). This element is "further away" (1up, 1sideways, 2down) from source than the right one in `#child2` (1up 1sideways 1down).

Comment: @Jamiec Very true, my script doesn't take into account how far away the sibling is, so a distant sibling might take precedence over a closer one.  I imagine it could be done by getting all of the siblings, checking their index in relation to the element and ordering them by the lowest difference.

Also my script assumes you aren't looking for siblings or children of the source.  But as you said, it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the specification correctly you mean something like the function closest defined below:

```
var allsources = $(".source");

function closest($source,selector) {
    if($source == null) return  $([]);
    var $matchingChildren = $source.find(selector);
    if($matchingChildren.length != 0) return $($matchingChildren.get(0));
    else return closest($source.parent(), selector)
}

allsources.click(closest($(this),'.target').hide();});
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/y2wJV/1/

Your definition requires that when choosing among matching children the function must return one that is less node hoops down/next/prev. This requirement has not been met, but this function is quite flexible and seems to do what you want to do in the case of the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code that is simple but does not solve the tie issue (returns the first)...

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.findClosest = function (filter) {
    var $found = $(),
            $currentSet = this; // Current place

    while ($currentSet.length) {
        $found = $currentSet.find(filter);
        if ($found.length) break; // At least one match: break loop
        // Get all children of the current set
        $currentSet = $currentSet.parent();
    }
    return $found.first(); // Return first match of the collection
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: My code is simpler and does the same that you're trying to achieve (if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: unless you need arbitrary filters, of course. Mine works only with filters that can be written as selectors.

Comment: yeah, yours is simpler, and I strongly like the "Keep It Simple" approach, therefore was marked as the correct answer. I still posted this one keeping in mind that latter on I could improve the logic in case of a tie to return the closes node in terms of less hoops. But either solutions work for me now since the markup has no ties.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, i had a table i needed to find the next element which may be outside the current td, so i made a jquery function:

```
    $.fn.nextAllLevels = function(sel) {
    if ($(this).nextAll(sel).length != 0) {
        return $(this).nextAll(sel).eq(0);
    } else if ($(this).nextAll(':has(' +  sel + ')').length != 0) {
        return $(this).nextAll(':has(' +  sel + ')').find(sel).eq(0);
    } else {
        return $(this).parent().nextAllLevels(sel);
    }
```

So to use this you simply call

```
$('#current').nextAllLevels('.target');
```

To give you the element closest in the foward direction, regardsless of whether in is in the current parent or not.