# find closest parent selector then find element by class

Tags: jquery

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641938/jquery-function-similar-to-closest-that-will-return-elements-outside-of-the-pare) the answers from here where helpful but didn't work for me.  My html is:

```
@foreach ($productSelection as $d)
                                            <div class="row justify-content-md-center el-selection vertical-align"
                                            data-type={{$selection}}
                                            data-id={{$d->id}}>
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                  <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $d->image_path) }}" alt=""
                                                          class="w-100 img-fluid blur-up lazyload image_zoom_cls-0">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <h6 class="product-title">{{ $d->name }}</h6>
                                                  <button class="btn btn-outline btn-sm detailsToggle">Show me details</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                              <p class="details-description" style="text-align: left; display: none" >{{ $d->description }}</p>
                                            </div>
                                          <hr/>
                                          @endforeach
```

this creates about 8 of these divs on the page.
My goal is to click the class `detailsToggle`and display the p element with class `details-description`

I have tried the following:

```
$( '.detailsToggle' ).click(function() {
  $( this )
  .closest('.row').find('.details-description').show()
})
```

In this same manner I tried .next, .siblings
.parents worked but it shows ALL elements with the class `.details-description`, which is not what I need.  I need only the element nearest/closest in the same row as the element clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try with `$( this ).closest('.row').next().find('.details-description').show()`. Since `details-description` is not part of the `.row`

Comment: That's it!  Thank you! @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: Alternatively, adjust your HTML so that the `.details-description` is *inside* (ie a child of) `.row`

Answer (score 2):

According to your jQuery code, Your HTML code should look like this:

```
@foreach ($productSelection as $d)
<div class="row justify-content-md-center el-selection vertical-align" data-type={{$selection}} data-id={{$d->id}} >
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $d->image_path) }}" alt="" class="w-100 img-fluid blur-up lazyload image_zoom_cls-0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h6 class="product-title">{{ $d->name }}</h6>
        <button class="btn btn-outline btn-sm detailsToggle">Show me details</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="details-description" style="text-align: left; display: none" >{{ $d->description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
@endforeach
```

Classes `.detailsToggle` and `.details-description` must be children of class `.row`.

Comment: It was answered in the comment: $( this ).closest('.row').next().find('.details-description').show()